# Function in Controller not being hit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-controller

First time asking a q, so if I'm doing something wrong, please let me know so I can fix it as I have tried finding the answer on here, but can not, so any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm trying to load a list of "Countries" using a controller and all seems to be going well, no errors, no warnings, it loads the module and hits the angular controller, but it never hits the function/goes into the code inside the function of the controller.  Am I missing something? Am I doing something wrong?

Register.cshtml

```
<div ng-app="RegisterApp" class="form-group" ng-controller="CountriesController as CountriesCtrl">
    <label class="input-desc">Country</label>
    <select ng-model="country" 
      ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in countries">
        <option value="{{CountriesCtrl.country.Id}}">{{CountriesCtrl.country.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div><!-- End .from-group -->
```

RegisterApp.js

```
var app = angular.module("RegisterApp", []);
```

CountriesService.js

```
/// <reference path="../App.js" />

angular.module("RegisterApp").service("CountriesService", function ($http) {
    this.getCountries = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "Get",
            url: "/Account/GetCountries"
        });
    };
});
```

CountriesController.js

```
/// <reference path="../Services/CountriesService.js" />

angular.module("RegisterApp").controller("CountriesController", function ($scope, CountriesService) {
    getCountries();

    function getCountries() {
        CountriesService.getCountries()
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.countries = data;
            $scope.country = $scope.countries[0];
        })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.message = 'Unexpected Error';
        });
    }
});
```

Edit:  Moved the ng-app, was mistakenly copied over like that, was a change I made just to try something before posting the q, sorry for that

Comment: Try using `app.service` and `app.controller` instead of `angular.module("RegisterApp").service...`. And also look at Sharikovs answer if you're missing the `ng-app` directive

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Arg0n, changed it back to use that, as it was how I had it initially, and changed the ng-app directive, still no go, it hits the controller, registers it successfully, but just skips over the code inside, no error or even a warning. Any other ideas perhaps...? Would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I added a new answer, and a working JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-app` must be registered before `ng-controller` (Or on same element). You have registered it in a child-element (`select`) to the element with `ng-controller`

Change your HTML to:

```
<div ng-app="RegisterApp" class="form-group" ng-controller="CountriesController as CountriesCtrl">
    <label class="input-desc">Country</label>
    <select ng-model="country" 
      ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in countries">
        <option value="{{CountriesCtrl.country.Id}}">{{CountriesCtrl.country.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/gj9xnhzg/6/) JSFiddle.

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help and especially for the fiddle, helped me get to the root of the problem.  It's working correctly now, it seems my registering of two modules also caused an issue, once I removed that and implemented your solution, all worked as it should. Thank you thank you thank you!

Comment: Sorry, tried to upvote but apparently not enough reputation yet :( Will come back as soon as I've earned enough!

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be:

```
<div ng-app="RegisterApp">
   <!-- some beautiful html -->
   <div class="form-group" ng-controller="CountriesController as CountriesCtrl">
        <label class="input-desc">Country</label>
        <select ng-model="country" ng-options="country.Id as country.Name for country in countries">
            <option value="{{CountriesCtrl.country.Id}}">{{CountriesCtrl.country.Name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <!-- some beautiful html -->
</div>
```

Notice ngApp directive usage.

Also, check that all of your dependencies are injected correctly (I mean `<head>` block)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the ng-app use to be in the div, I moved it to the select to see if it would change anything, it did not, moved it back now again, still no go.  With regards to dependencies, I've changed it from using just the controller in the same js file as the app to separating it with the service to see if it changes anything.  The issue is that there is no error being thrown, it hits the controller and seems to successfully register the controller, but just skips over the code inside it.  Anything else you can possible think of that could be causing this issue?